# SaltStack: Is there a way to only display failed and warnings in output?

Tags: saltstack

Running **state.apply** or **state.highstate** on minions can result in hundreds of lines in output. Sometimes only one minion can be enough.

```
...
Summary for my_minion
--------------
Succeeded: 112 (changed=78)
Failed:      6
Warnings:    1
--------------
Total states run:     118
Total run time:     4.958 s
```

Is there a way to show only failed and warnings in the output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the `state_output` in master's configuration file.

It is also possible to override the state output from the command line, like:

`salt '*' state.apply --state-output=mixed`

Take a look at the documentation for more information about the [`state-output`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/salt.output.highstate.html).

Comment: Thanks for this - this is super helpful for when there's more than 10-20 states (I've got around ~1500)

Answer (score 7):

I usually use:

```
salt '*' state.apply -l quiet --state-verbose=false
```

that shows only change/failed states

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSON output, then filter out the successful entries with `jq`.

```
salt-run jobs.lookup_jid 20180318whatever --out=json | \
jq 'map_values(with_entries(select(.value.result|not)))'
```